# Paypal sandbox exchange rate is two times the real one

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, currency, currency-exchange-rates

Paypal sandbox acts weirdly:
I make payment of 700 RUB(Russian currency) to USD Seller account.
700 RUB in the real world is something around 10 USD, but when I make this payment in sandbox I got the conversion to 22.55 USD. I would understand difference +/-10%, but this is more than double the real price. Unfortunately I can't test such conversion on the real paypal accounts now, but paypal guy says that "the currency conversion you see in Sandbox accurately reflects our rates at that time." - https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Selling-on-your-website/Completely-inaccurate-currency-conversion/td-p/184328?profile.language=en-gb
So how is it possible and what is the problem? Did anyone have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's an API you can use to get the real time conversion rate that PayPal uses https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ConvertCurrency_API_Operation/